# Linux Mint: Power Management does not turn off displayport monitor

Tags: linux-mint, power-management, displayport

I have two monitors connected to this system... one via displayport and one via DVI. When I go into the screen saver settings, I enabled Power Management and set standby, suspend, and off to 1 minute. After that minute, the DVI monitor goes black as expected (backlight turns off, and the power light changes to amber signaling power save mode), but the displayport monitor power light stays blue, screen is black but the backlight remains on.

How should I go about starting to diagnose this issue? I want to make sure that both monitors completely go into power save mode after a specified time frame.

FWIW this machine has an Nvidia Quadro K600, and I have the proprietary Nvidia drivers installed. Monitors are both ASUS PB278Q

Answer (score 0):

I just connected a LG 34UM95 21:9 monitor and am having the same issues with LinuxMint 17.

The only way I can get it to work properly is to use DisplayPort 1.1 instead of 1.2 in the monitor settings.

Of course this limits framerate to 30 instead of 60 so it's far from ideal.

Comment: We’re looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.  And we don't really need a lot of detail on your version of the problem; focus on the solution.  Unsupported anecdotes like "I tried X and it worked for me" are better posted as comments.

Comment: @G-Man I don't think this is an unsupported anecdote. It's a solution to the question—perhaps not a perfect one, but I'm not sure where it needs more explanations…

Comment: @slhck: Well, it’s unsupported in the sense that there's no explanation of why it should work.  Neither is there an explanation of how to execute the procedure; perhaps it’s enough that anybody who uses DisplayPort would understand it.  ISTM that I've seen answers at least as substantial as this one get downvoted and/or deleted.  It certainly starts off sounding like “I’m having this problem, too”, and even the author seems not to regard it as a solution (he said, “I’m still trying to solve it ...”).

Comment: @G-Man There *is* a solution here. We don't necessarily care about *why* something works if the author doesn't even know or if it is irrelevant. Of course it'd be nice to know, but the main goal is to help visitors who have a similar problem. Deleting this answer doesn't achieve that goal. I do agree there could be an explanation of how to change the monitor settings, but that's a minor point.